# Incompatible types for CompletableSource using Completable

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to handle error (ignore it) when it occurs in my upper observable chain stream. 
I want to use `onErrorResumeNext` function to do this.
However when i using it like thisl

```
.... //some actions
.onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, CompletableSource>() {
        @Override
        public CompletableSource apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
         return Completable.complete();
        }
      })
```

The IDE underlines the `return Completable.complete()` line with error:

> Incompatible types.
>   Required:
>   io.reactivex.CompletableSource
>   Found:
>   rx.Completable

How to handle this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import the correct type:

```java
import io.reactivex.Completable;
```

or

```java
return io.reactivex.Completable.complete();
```